# How to select rows based on a condition for a common value of a specific column?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Sorry for a confusing title, I don't know how to put it clearly.

This is what I want to do accomplish using PySpark SQL:

When Value for Variable 'Z' is between 2000 and 3000 return rows for that specific ID, but only return data for Variables Y and Z.

I don't know how to go further than with the query below, how to let SQL know that we need to choose the proper IDs (2 and 3) in the attached df?

```
 SELECT ID, Variable, Date, Value 
 FROM TABLE 
 WHERE (Variable == 'Y' OR Variable == 'Z') AND "if Value of Z between 2000 and 3000 then select only these IDs"
```

[image: Top is the df, bottom is the expected result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using simple inner query

```sql
 SELECT ID, Variable, Date, Value 
 FROM TABLE 
 WHERE (Variable == 'Y' OR Variable == 'Z') AND ID in (select id from TABLE where variable = 'Z' and value between 2000 and 3000)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spark, I would recommend using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when variable = 'Z' and z_value between 2000 and 3000 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as z_value_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where variable in ('Y', 'Z') and z_value_cnt >= 1;
```

I would expect this to have a better execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'X', '01/01/20',5),
                      (1,'Y', '01/01/20',10),
                      (1,'Z', '01/01/20',1000),
                      (2,'X', '01/02/20',20),
                      (2,'Y', '01/02/20',30),
                      (2,'Z', '01/02/20',2500)],['ID','VAR','DATE','VAL'])
display(df.filter("VAL Between 2000 and 3000").select('ID').join(df,['ID']).filter("VAR in ('X','Y')"))
```